# How do I get apache on Rackspace Cloud Sites to serve scripts with extra path info?

Tags: apache2, rackspace, pathinfo

I'm running a site on Rackspace Cloud Sites (I don't have access to the apache configuration, but I can potentially ask them to change something or enable me to make the changes).

I have a script called feeds.php and I want to put it in the document root so that it will be script called when requests come in for uris like /feeds/news or /feeds/photos.

All of the apache servers that I run on machines I directly control seem to do this by default. When I put that feeds.php on my other apache sites, it works as I intend it. It's not working on Rackspace Cloud Sites though. I've got a ticket open with them, but I'm trying to understand what it causing this functionality so that I can fix it myself in the future (or at least better describe to Rackspace support what I need).

I've grepped through all of my Apache configs on the server where this is working and I don't have any RewriteRules or anything that would do this.

Do you know what configuration options make Apache server urls in this fasion?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create some re-write rules and make sure URL ReWriting is enabled.

You can use this site to help generate the rules you need:

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Comment: That's what I keep getting told, but this works on my other apache site and I haven't set up any rules like that. That's what confuses me, because I'm getting this functionality without the RewriteBase or RewriteRules that you'd use to accomplish this.

Comment: Are your other sites running on Cloud Sites with Apache?

Comment: No, just running Apache on a linux box. I've tried figuring out what is in my apache config on my local box which enables this, but I can't find anything and I can't find any references to RewriteBase at all.

Comment: Strange. In your Apache config file do you have ReWrite On? If not try adding it, then turn ReWrite logging on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog

Comment: Yes, I do have mod_rewrite enabled and I am using it for other, very simple things (like sending a 301 redirect for defunct urls), but I don't have any RewriteBase directives at all which appear to be one of the essential steps in enabling the functionality under discussion. And since I don't have any of those directives, I'm very confused.